# How do I import a private key into GPG so that it becomes the default key?

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to share a GnuPG key pair by importing it into each machine. This is how I'm doing it:

```
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import secret.gpg.key
gpg --import public.gpg.key
```

The keys have been exported with `-a`.

After doing this, the public key is shown correctly when I do a `gpg --list-keys`, but the private key isn't (`gpg --list-secret-keys`).

What am I doing wrong?

By the way: I'm doing this with Puppet, so any solution that doesn't require me to type stuff in (`--edit-key` and the like) would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what is wrong with the `gpg --list-secret-keys` output? There's no flag for GPG to mark a key to be default. It just picks the first one in that list to be the default. If you need to change that behaviour, I can provide an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To change the GnuPG behaviour on what key it selects on signing/encryption, use the `default-key` configuration parameter with the key ID as the value.

So, for example, with

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys 
/home/gert/.gnupg/secring.gpg
-----------------------------
sec   4096R/13371337 2011-01-01 [expires: 2014-01-01]
uid                  Gert van Dijk (1st key) <name@example.tld>
ssb   4096R/31337313 2011-01-01

sec   4096R/12345678 2013-04-23 [expires: 2014-01-01]
uid                  Gert van Dijk (2nd key) <name@example.tld>
ssb   4096R/87654321 2013-04-23
```

add a line in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`:

```
default-key 12345678
```

or, alternatively, use the long key ID (recommended as short key IDs can have collisions):

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --with-colon
sec::4096:1:ABCDEFAB12345678:2013-01-01:2014-01-01:::Gert van Dijk (2nd key) <user@example.tld>:::
```

and add a line in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`:

```
default-key ABCDEFAB12345678
```

Comment: By default the first one of the list of `gpg --list-secret-keys` will be used as the default key — is that correct?